# has_and_belongs_to_many on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck with Laravel (also new to it), readed the Many-to-Many relationship documentation and still can't find out what's my problem.

I have a model Company that looks like:

```
class Company extends Eloquent 
{
  public static $timestamps = true;

  public function owner()
  {
    return $this -> belongs_to('User', 'owner_id');
  }

  public function users()
  {
    return $this -> has_and_belongs_to_many('User', 'company_users');
  }
}
```

Also, I have a model User that looks like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
  public static $timestamps = true;

  public function companies() 
  {
    return $this -> has_and_belongs_to_many('Company');
  }
}
```

I have a user saved to the database that has ID 1, so I do

```
  $user = User::find(1);
  var_dump($user -> companies() -> get());

  $company = new Company();
  $company -> name = 'name';
  $company -> owner_id = $user -> id;

  $company -> save();
```

Question is, how do I save the owner inside of the users() of the company?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit and add your migrations? Also, can you explain to me a little better on what exactly your trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you save your company, attach the user to it, something like this:

```
$company->users()->attach($user->id);
```

This will ensure that the `$user->id` is added to the `company_users` table with the `$company->id`

Answer (score 1):

"Question is, how do I save the owner inside of the users() of the company?"

What you have is two separate relationships that you need to keep in sync. I would overload the save method on the Company model such that when the user_id (owner) is changed, the new owner id is added to the users relationship.

```
// Something like this, untested, etc...
public function save()
{
    parent::save();

    if ( $this->changed( 'user_id' ) )
    {
        $this->users()->attach( $this->user_id );
    }
}
```